# Scheduled callback with Amazon Connect

Tags: amazon-connect

Is it possible to build a flow that allows a user to schedule a callback from an Amazon Connect queue using the StartOutboundVoiceContact API?

Comment: You can use StartOutboundVoiceContact API to make automate outbound calls. But I think you have to schedule it from your end.

Answer (score 0):

It more about building something to do the scheduling or with Amazon Connect tasks you can create a task for an agent or queue to process the callback